# Web Images Not Clear on Windows Phone

Tags: image, windows-phone-8.1, ie-mobile

I'm creating a mobile website and it has some graphics on. I've found that the images display clearly on both iOS and Android, however, on my Windows Phone they are showing up blurry.

I've tried changing file format and increasing and decreasing the resolution, But they still don't display clearly.

Thanks :)

The image below shows the site on the two devices. Left = Windows Phone - Right= iPod Touch

[Screenshot of Screens](http://s13.postimg.org/uy0pzsurb/web_pic1.png)

Comment: can you provide specifics about the images (format, resolution), the markup you are using to display them, and the specific phone you are using to view them on?

Comment: @PeterTorr I'm using .png images. They are 500px-500px @ 100ppi. I'm using the <img> tags with width=100% height=auto so they span the device screen. I'm using Nokia Lumia 630 w/ WP8.1 Cyan + Developers Preview.

Comment: Thanks for info. The image will be scaled down on the Nokia (screen is 480px wide, less any page margins) so I expect some distortion. The image will be scaled up slightly for the iPod (screen is 640px wide) but you will notice the distortion less due to the higher pixel density. I assume you scaled down the iPod screenshot so it was 500px wide?

Comment: @petertorr I did scale it down so it would fit side by side. Should I then create a 480px of my graphics for the lower res screen?

Comment: Yes, creating a lower-res version is better. Note that it might not be a full 480px wide, depending on what margins etc are in effect on the page. I would verify the exact rendered size of the image and then create it that big. Did you use an old iPod? Apple's website says it is 640px.

Comment: @Alexander Wright, did you ever figure this out? I'm having the exact same problem with large images on Windows Phone.

Comment: @MCM Did anyone ever figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you are using `Data Sense settings`? This might be happening if you leave it to High or Automatic. According to the documentation found on the [Use Data Sense to manage data usage](https://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/connectivity/use-data-sense-to-manage-data-usage) page

> Tap High to have Data Sense save even more data by compressing pictures, blocking some ads, and downloading only part of a web page.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I'm on WiFi, but I turned them off and the page still displays blurry images.